# Was ist die Wortherkunft von von erstere und letztere?

Tags: etymology

Gelegentlich lese ich [erstere/ ersterer/ ersteres](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/erstere) oder [letztere/ letzterer/ letzteres](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/letztere), beziehungsweise die Substantivierungen von diesen. Aus meinem persönlichen Sprachempfinden heraus habe ich es immer als Steigerung von erstes, beziehungsweise letztes empfunden. Da es in einer Reihe von Ereignissen oder Dingen jeweils nur einen ersten und einen letzten Eintrag geben kann, hielt ich diese Worte als umgangssprachliche Schöpfungen, in Schrift demnach inkorrekt.
Der Duden bietet Einträge dieser Worte an, jedoch ohne Herkunft auch ohne Verweis auf Umgangssprache, daher gehe ich davon aus, dass sie korrekt sind. Leider konnte ich auch in anderen frei verfügbaren Online-Wörterbüchern keine Erklärung der Wortherkunft finden.

Aus den Artikeln des Dudens konnte ich entnehmen, dass es sich um Synonyme für erstgenanntes, beziehungsweise letztgenanntes handelt, der Bedeutungserklärung nach zu urteilen.

Was ist der Ursprung dieser Worte? Wenn es sich um eine Kontraktion handelt, so kann ich mir nicht erklären, aus welchen Wortteilen sie abzuleiten wäre. Seit wann sind diese Worte in Gebrauch? Beziehen sie sich immer auf eine Aufzählung und können daher nur relativ dazu verwendet werden?

Würde man sie sprachlich und semantisch als guten Stil bezeichnen oder gibt es eindeutigere Wendungen? Folgendes Beispiel wäre wahrscheinlich korrekt, jedoch schwer verständlich.

> Im 100 m Sprint ist Peter Letzter geworden. Paul ist Zweiter geworden. Letzterer unterlag nur Rainer. Ersterer hatte Probleme mit seinen Schuhen.

Gibt es Situationen, in denen solche Konstruktionen notwendig wären, weil sie sich nicht einfacher oder kürzer umschreiben lassen. Folgendes enthält dieselben Informationen, kommt jedoch ohne den Gebrauch von erstere/ letztere aus:

> Da Peter Probleme mit seinen Schuhen hatte, ist er im 100 m Sprint Letzter geworden. Paul ist Zweiter geworden, er unterlag nur Rainer.

Die Betonung ist hier natürlich eine Andere, der Gedankengang wäre aber deutlicher nachvollziehbar für mich. (Sprachlich könnte auch dieses Beispiel noch verbessert werden.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beide, [ersterer](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GE08787#XGE08787) und letzterer sollen nach Grimm aus einem Superlativ (erste, letzte) im Neuhochdeutschen entstandener Komparative sein:

> ERSTERE, *prior, ein, wie in den sprachen oft geschieht, aus dem superlativ neu vorquellender comparativ. [...] wir sahen* erste, êristo *aus* êriro, *goth.* airiza *entspringen und dem* anterior *die bedeutung von* prior *beigelegt, so dasz nun* êristo, erste *auch* primus *ausdrücken konnte.* êristo *wie* primus *erschienen dann wieder als positive und zeugten den neuen comp.* erstere, *gerade wie aus dem superl. der* letzte *wieder ein comp.* **letztere** *entsprosz.*

Offenbar handelt es sich also nicht um eine umgangssprachliche Neuschöpfung, sondern um ein Adjektiv, das so seit dem 17. Jahrhundert Verwendung findet.

Anzumerken ist noch, dass man *Ersterer* und *Letzterer* in substantivischer Verwendung nach heutiger Rechtschreibung (§57.1) [groß schreibt](http://canoonet.eu/spelling/erstere:A:Comp):

> Der Erstere wollte ans Meer, die Letztere in die Berge.
>   ..., denn Ersteres bedeutet nichts und Letzteres alles.

Zu Verwendung kann man sagen, dass durch die Superlative eine absolute Position entsteht, während es bei der Verwendung der Komparative um die Beschreibung der Stellung in einer Reihe geht.

Answer (score 1):

*Ersteres* und *Letzteres* sind natürlich keine Steigerungen - Zuallererst, weil beide nicht zu steigern sind, aber natürlich auch von der Wortbedeutung nicht.

"Brauchen" tut man beide, wenn im ersten Hauptsatz die Hauptaussage liegt, die man nicht mit irgendwelchen Nebensätzen verwässern will wie in deinem Beispiel. Die Tatsache, dass Peter Letzter und Paul Zweiter geworden ist, steht im ersten Beispiel wesentlich mehr im Vordergrund, während die Gründe dafür eher nebensächlich sind.

Aufgabe beider Worte ist, ein Substantiv über eine Satzgrenze zu tragen, wie z.B. in

*Das Haus ist grün angestrichen. Es steht in der Goethestrasse.*

*Peter ist von Beruf Jäger. Er ist 42 Jahre alt.*

Will man sich auf mehr als ein Substantiv über Satzgrenzen hinweg beziehen, muss man eben sagen was was ist. Ich denke, es ist kein Zufall, dass es und *er* aus dem Beispiel oben auch in *Ersteres* und *ersterer* vorkommen. Die gefragten Wörter sind genauso Stellvertreterpronomen wie *Er* und *Es* in meinem Beispiel. In manchen Dialekten darf man *Es Erste* sagen - Das dürfte ein deutlicher Hinweis auf die Wortentstehung sein.